# Google GMOCK build libgmock.a under windows

Tags: cmake, googletest, googlemock

I try to build the gmock library from google under windows, avialable on github from here: 
https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/master/googlemock

I tried to use cmake in the cygwin console, but I could not build it.

```
cmake C:\Users\Username\Downloads\googlemock-master\googlemock-master\googlemock

"CMake Error: The source directory "C:UsersSETDownloadsgooglemock-mastergooglemock-mastergooglemock" does not exist.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI."
```

Then I installed visual studio 2017 and opened the gmock.sln file, but also this build failed.

```
"Error C1083: "gtest/internal/gtest-linked_ptr.h": No such file or directory    gmock   C:\Users\Username\Downloads\googlemock-master\googlemock-master\googlemock\include\gmock\internal\gmock-port.h"
```

Does anyone have an idea how I could build this library under windows 10?

Edit: Ok, for cmake the path needs to have /../ and not ..\, but i still don't get which path I need to include in cmake

Answer (score 2):

Very simple:

- Under the `googlemock` folder, create  a new folder, named `build` (for example);
- `cd build && cmake ..`

Basically, you're creating a new folder for the build (preferably inside the project tree, but not necessary), cd into it, and run `cmake <dir>`, where `<dir>` is the path to `CMakeLists.txt`, which contains the recipe for generating the build.

That's it. Now you'll have a generated `gmock.sln`, which you could build with Visual Studio.

For CMake to generate Visual Studio projects, you should have the Visual Studio binaries and Windows SDK reachable from your `PATH`.

Finally, you need to specify a generator, using CMake's `-G` parameter, for telling CMake which Visual Studio version you'd like projects to be generated for.

Example of putting this together:

```
set PATH="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin";"c:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86";%PATH%  
cd build
cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015" ..
```

For additional instructions, you may refer to googletest github page:
https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/README.md#using-cmake